# Base Year Conversions for Provincial Level GDP

Tags: dataset

I have provincial level GDP data for Pakistan from 1970 to 2010-11.
The data estimates are taken from two sources i.e. Sustainable Development Policy Institute (SDPI), Pakistan, and World Bank.

The provincial GDP data from 1970-71 to 1999-00 is based on 1980-81 factor cost (source: SDPI). And the provincial GDP data from 1999-00 to 2010-11 is based on 1999-00 factor prices (source: World Bank); this World Bank Data is also available in current prices.

I wish to convert this data into the same base-year. For example, I would want to have all this data in 1999-00 factor costs.

I am not able to figure out how to do these base-year conversations. 
It will be very helpful if someone can help me out with this.

Thank you.